# eth1 ip address not showing 14.04

Tags: virtualbox-networking

When I run `ifconfig` in my virtual machine (which is running Ubuntu), I cannot see the [eth1 ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p5wz.png) address of my machine.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try `ifconfig eth1` it gives output for the `eth1` port only.

Also keep in mind that Linux, and all other systems for that matter, start counting at 0. If you only have one nic installed you should be looking for `eth0`.

If you do have 2 nic's  installed use `sudo`, `vim` or `less` to check `/etc/network` for available nic's and look for a file called `interfaces,` you can either run `cat interfaces` or `less interfaces` to view available nic's.

Comment: if there is only one interface in your linux and you are sure you need/want two interfaces, try going to your vitual machine settings and see if both NIC's are connected using the `enable network adapter` checkbox in your 'Network' setting tab. If not, shut down your VM, check the checkbox and start your VM again.